# Can we split Sqoop job by multiple column combination

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am using below Sqoop syntax to split Sqoop job by single column[mostly primary key].

> sqoop import --connect  jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle_server:1521/sid --username xxx  --password xxx  --table EMPLOYEE --split-by ID -m 10

Can we use multiple columns as combination, if primary key is not available to split Sqoop job?

> sqoop import --connect  jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle_server:1521/sid --username xxx  --password xxx  --table EMPLOYEE --split-by **FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME** -m 10

Answer (score 5):

No. We can use only one column in Split-by otherwise you will get the error message - Invalid column name 'FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME'.

Please note that if you do not have the split-by column, then you have to explicitly set the --num-mappers 1 or -m 1